# 'from file import class' tries to import other classes as well

Tags: python, class, import

I'm trying to learn python by making a game, and I'm trying to import the troop class from my `d5` game file to the current one. This class only has variables in it and I want to use these in both files:

```
import pygame as pg
import random as rd
import sys
sys.path.append('C:/Users/hornu/OneDrive/Dungeon')
from d5 import troops
```

Here is the class it should import:

```
class troops:

    Goblins=[3,0,7,1,'small','living',['scout'],False,['Goblin','Goblins']]
    Skeletons=[6,4,3,2,'normal','undead',[None],False,['Skeleton','Skeletons']]
    Ogres=[9,0,19,3,'large','living',[None],False,['Ogre','Ogres']]
    Demons=[10,2,13,3,'normal','magical',[None],False,['Demon','Demons']]
    Bosses=[20,3,35,5,'large','living',[None],False,['Boss','Bosses']]

    Peasants=[1,0,9,1,'normal','undead',[None],False,['Peasant','Peasants']]
    Militia=[4,1,9,2,'normal','living',[None],False,['Militiaman','Militiamen']]
    Squires=[6,1,12,3,'normal','living',['scout'],False,['Squire','Squires']]
    Knights=[10,3,15,3,'normal','living',[None],False,['Knight','Knights']]
    Paladins=[15,3,15,4,'normal','living',[None],False,['Paladin','Paladins']]
```

My problem is that after importing the troops class it continues importing other classes from the file as well as going into imports declared in the second file, until it reaches a class it can't import (because it's in a third file I didn't give a path to) and then it quits with an error. As far as I can tell, the class I want gets imported properly, I just don't get why it keeps importing other things.
I'm sure I just don't fully understand how imports work yet, but it seems strange that it keeps going. How can I get it to import only the single class and stop? Or should I be using a completely different approach for this?

Thanks!

Comment: when you import a class, all imports from file that this class is in, are executed as well. For example, if my class `x` (that is in `x.py`) needs `os` module to work (so there is `import os` in `x.py`), then after I run `from x import x` the `import os` is executed.

Comment: try the answer[edited now]

Comment: @Rafaó Okay, I understand that part, but I can circumvent that. However the real problem is that other, unrelated classes are also getting imported from the file, and that's where it fails. I don't get why are other classes getting imported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import works better for `Function` rather than for a  `Class` when you want to import something specific from a script. So try using:

```
def troops():

    return [[3,0,7,1,'small','living',['scout'],False,['Goblin','Goblins']]
    ,[6,4,3,2,'normal','undead',[None],False,['Skeleton','Skeletons']]
    ,[9,0,19,3,'large','living',[None],False,['Ogre','Ogres']]
    ,[10,2,13,3,'normal','magical',[None],False,['Demon','Demons']]
    ,[20,3,35,5,'large','living',[None],False,['Boss','Bosses']]
    ,[1,0,9,1,'normal','undead',[None],False,['Peasant','Peasants']]
    ,[4,1,9,2,'normal','living',[None],False,['Militiaman','Militiamen']]
    ,[6,1,12,3,'normal','living',['scout'],False,['Squire','Squires']]
    ,[10,3,15,3,'normal','living',[None],False,['Knight','Knights']]
    ,[15,3,15,4,'normal','living',[None],False,['Paladin','Paladins']]]
```

Now use:

```
from d5 import troops
Goblins,Skeletons,Ogres,Demons,Bosses,Peasants,Militia,Squires,Knights,Paladins=troops()
```